# Controling matplotlib xtick step when using datetime

Tags: python, matplotlib

Sorry for this answer but I am not understanding well the solutions I read, so here is the question:

I have some series to plot:

```
sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=21)
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=21)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(x_a, y_a)
plt.plot(x_b, y_b)
plt.plot(x_c, y_c)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=5)
plt.legend(['A', 'C', 'D'], loc=2,  prop={'size': 25})
```

And I get this:

[image]

But when I increase the number of series, I get this:
[image]

xticks are automatically adjusted, but how can I manage to turn them the same in both graphs?

Comment: see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_demo_rrule.html).

Comment: @RafaelHiga  You can rotate your `xaxis` tick to 90 degree by default